# slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method type error when bi-sectioning a list

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering, bisection

I'm geeting the above error when trying to run the code to bi-section the the cItems list - code was taken from Python 2.7 and now needs to run on 3.6 - any ideas?

```
    cItems = [[8, 3, 9, 2, 10, 1, 7, 5, 4, 6]]

    cItems=[i[j:k] for i in cItems for j,k in ((0,len(i)/2), (len(i)/2,len(i))) if len(i)>1] # bi-section

    TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: You forgot `range`?

Comment: unfortunately no - sorry, forgot to include that it runs inside a 'while' loop
        'while len(cItems)>:
            cItems=[i[j:k] for i in cItems for j,k in ((0,len(i)/2), (len(i)/2,len(i))) if len(i)>1] # bi-section'

the code works in 2.7 but can't figure out what I have to change to make it run in 3.6

Answer (score 0):

```
cItems=[i[j:k] for i in cItems for j,k in ((0,int(len(i)/2)),(int(len(i)/2),len(i))) if len(i)>1]
```

this would be the change you need